# NSNetwork error after starting NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I use `NSURLSession` to download files in background. Here is how I start a new  `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[self nextURL]];
_task = [[self downloadSession] downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:nil];
[_task resume];
```

After calling `resume`, I encountered the following error:

```
nsnetworkd[1557] <Error>: Couldn't add download <SSDownload: 0x16d63a20>: 958545229883046269 to download manager
```

After this, no `delegate` methods were called (it seems like the session was killed). The internet connection was ok (Safari was able to open websites).

It occurred only once on iOS 7.0.4. Can someone please explain what could this error mean? Is this an iOS 7.0.x bug or is there a good workaround?

Comment: Why aren't you using `downloadTaskWithResumeData:completionHandler:` if you are trying to resume a previous download?

Comment: @Wain I don't try to resume a previous download, I start a new one.

Comment: Before I bet on an iOS bug, I'd first look to make sure you have your delegate properly assigned and implemented.